# SQL-null value showing in the output when there is a value present in the database

Tags: sql, database, duplicates

I am extracting values from two different tables in the database. I should get only one line of output but instead I am getting two lines. One of the output line is perfect but the other line has one null value which clearly should not be null. My code is as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DEATH_RATE.COUNTRY_NAME, 
                DEATH_RATE.DATA_YEAR,  
                DEATH_RATE.DEATH_RATE_VALUE,
                TIME_TO_EXPORT.EXPORT_VALUE
FROM DEATH_RATE, TIME_TO_EXPORT 
WHERE TIME_TO_EXPORT.COUNTRY_NAME IN ('Belgium')
AND TIME_TO_EXPORT.COUNTRY_NAME = DEATH_RATE.COUNTRY_NAME
AND DEATH_RATE.DATA_YEAR = 2012 
AND DEATH_RATE.DATA_YEAR = DEATH_RATE.DATA_YEAR ;
```

The output I am getting is as follows:

```
 COUNTRY_NAME   DATA_YEAR   DEATH_RATE   EXPORT_VALUE
1.Belgium         2012         423.5       9
2.Belgium         2012         423.5      null
```

First line is fine and only that should have been the output. Where is the second line and the null coming from ??

Thanks

Comment: in your where clause just add `AND TIME_TO_EXPORT.EXPORT_VALUE IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Instead of extracting values like the way you're doing, try to fetch by joining these tables..

Comment: because your TIME_TO_EXPORT table with country name Belgium  having EXPORT_VALUE as nul.thats wwhy its comming as null.

Comment: it is not null..that's why in the first line it is showing 9 which is the actual value.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You should also get used to an explicit `JOIN` operator instead of the ancient and fragile implicit join condition in the where clause

Comment: Do you have any common field between those fields?

Comment: Please edit your input table values into your question. Confirm that that output is what you actually got from that input and that query. Read about SO MCVEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last condition of your query is a bit useless (the condition is always `true` when the value is not `null`):

```
DEATH_RATE.DATA_YEAR = DEATH_RATE.DATA_YEAR
```

I think you intended that :

```
TIME_TO_EXPORT.DATA_YEAR = DEATH_RATE.DATA_YEAR
```

*(I assume that the fields have the same name)*
In your select, you were thus getting all the `TIME_TO_EXPORT` records related to 'Belgium' whatever the value of `DATA_YEAR`.

So your query becomes :

```
SELECT DISTINCT DEATH_RATE.COUNTRY_NAME, 
                DEATH_RATE.DATA_YEAR,  
                DEATH_RATE.DEATH_RATE_VALUE,
                TIME_TO_EXPORT.EXPORT_VALUE
FROM DEATH_RATE, TIME_TO_EXPORT 
WHERE TIME_TO_EXPORT.COUNTRY_NAME IN ('Belgium')
AND TIME_TO_EXPORT.COUNTRY_NAME = DEATH_RATE.COUNTRY_NAME
AND DEATH_RATE.DATA_YEAR = 2012 
AND TIME_TO_EXPORT.DATA_YEAR = DEATH_RATE.DATA_YEAR ;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That is right but I would qualify it more as a side effect than an intention. Isn't it a terrible way to check if a value is not `null`?

Comment: Yeah that was the problem..My Bad!!..Too much copy pasting. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Replace your last line with this:

```
AND TIME_TO_EXPORT.DATA_YEAR = DEATH_RATE.DATA_YEAR;
```

Answer (score 0):

DEATH_RATE are TIME_TO_EXPORT are not properly join. and of course last line has no meaning.